# Como/onde hospedar um WebService?

Tags: web-service

Olá, participo de um projeto voluntário em minha faculdade e gostaria de criar um Web Service para ajudar no processo interno e aprender um pouco mais sobre o assunto. Nossa equipe possui o seguinte ambiente:

- Um site hospedado na Hostgator.
- Um software que utiliza o banco de dados fornecido pela Hostgator.

Porém, gostaria de criar um sistema para interagir o site, o software e mais um aplicativo (Android e iOS), por isso a necessidade de criação do Web Service. A ideia inicial era criá-lo em java, pois tenho mais experiência e facilidade em lidar com a linguagem, porém a Hostgator não suporta Java, como fui informado pelo suporte. Além de quê, acredito que os serviços de hospedagem de sites não podem ser utilizados para manter um Web Service.

Ai vem as dúvidas:

- Existe alguma maneira de hospedar o site e o web service em um mesmo serviço de hospedagem? Como?
- Se não for possível, existe um outro tipo de serviço em que eu possa manter os dois ou eu tenho que deixar o site lá mesmo e o Web Service em outro serviço?

Já pesquisei aqui e em outros fóruns, porém não achei uma resposta que respondesse totalmente.

Se conhecerem algum curso, vídeo aula, bibliografia, site, tutorial que possam complementar as respostas, seria de grande ajuda.

Comment: Felipe, sou leigo também mas tenha uma sugestão. E se você pudesse criar o webservice em Java mesmo, hospedar em um computador da faculdade que não seja desligado e utilizar serviços como no-ip ou ddns para acessá-lo? Já pensou em uma solução assim? Eu sei que pode não ser a melhor coisa, mas talvez para início do projeto possa ajudar.

Comment: Podes pegar um computador da amazon e montar o que precisares lá.
Há também a possibilidade de utilizar o heroku
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#introduction

Comment: @RodrigoTognin essa foi uma das primeiras soluções que eu tentei, mas minha faculdade é meio restrita pra deixar os alunos utilizarem desses serviços :s E também por ser um projeto guiado somente por alunos seria um aprendizado bacana fazer isso tudo do zero. Mas agradeço a ajuda de qualquer forma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa de algumas coisas para ter um WebService, em Java, não vou poder passar nenhum auxilio, porém nessa resposta vou tentar te auxiliar em como hospedar um WebService.

A resposta é que é relativemente possível fazer um WebService em uma hospedagem compartilhada na Hostgator, porém você acabaria tendo alguns problemas, e acredito que o principal deles seria debugar o código em produção, ja que não teria acesso a um shell.

Agora, de forma onde seria até de manutenção mais fácil, você possuir um servidor EC2 na AWS, se sua aplicação não necessitar de muitos recursos, podes até utilizar a camada gratuita por um período, no server EC2 poderias publicar tanto o site, como o WebService, claro que vai precisar tomar mais cuidado com as configurações de segurança do servidor, firewall, proxy, ou seja lá o que quiser usar, mas não foi esse o caso da pergunta.

> Como criar uma instancia do EC2

- Acesse [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/)
- Crie uma conta, ative o cartão de crédito válido, você não será cobrada, mas é necessário para liberar a camada free.
- Dentro do seu console pesquise por 'EC2', clique em 'EC2'
- Clique em 'launch instance', siga os passos para criar a instancia free.

> Crie o banco de dados na AWS

- Dentro do console pesquise por 'RDS', clique em 'RDS'
- Clique em 'instances'
- Clique em 'Launch DB instances'
- Siga os passos para criar a instancia grátis de acordo com o banco de dados que for utilizar.

> Para publicar

- Desenvolva o seu projeto em seu ambiente local.
- Configure sua instancia exatamente como seu ambiente local.
- Troque os endpoints locais para os endpoints de sua instancia.
- Suba seu projeto em alguma hospedagem de projetos, se utilizarem i [GIT](https://git-scm.com/) podes salvar seu projeto no [GitLab](https://gitlab.com), que permite salvar projetos privados gratuitamente.
- Entre em sua instancia via SSH, baixe e rode seu projeto.

O Google também oferece uma camada gratuita para testar suas VM's, você teria algo muito parecido com [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/), porém acredito que a AWS seja mais fácil de entender caso nunca tenha operado com isso.

Refs:

[EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/ec2/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_BR&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=english_ec2_b&sc_content=ec2_p&sc_detail=ec2&sc_category=ec2&sc_segment=176355371688&sc_matchtype=p&sc_country=BR&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!176355371688!p!!g!!ec2&ef_id=Wy-I0QAADY9cs5J_:20180712001419:s)
[RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/rds/mysql/)

*Claro que estou considerando que saberás configurar o servidor, caso não saiba como comente que complemento a resposta, apagarei em breve esse trecho.*

Comment: Acredito que a DigitalOcean também seria uma oção muito boa...

Comment: @AnthraxisBR muito obrigado. Era exatamente isso que eu procurava, estou começando a trabalhar com Web Services e minha maior dificuldade está sendo essa e não encontrei muitas informações sobre isso na internet. Tentarei implementar da forma como me indicou e pesquisar mais sobre o assunto para assimilar melhor as suas dicas, mas foi de grande ajuda, obrigado mesmo!!

Comment: @EvertonGouveia obrigado pela recomendação, pesquisarei mais sobre!!

Comment: @FelipeMartins Ainda bem que ajudou hehe, se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, podia aceitar clicando no 'check' verdinho, assim outras pessoas podem saber que essa dúvida ja está resolvida ;).